# Cannot change API Level on Android Studio

Tags: android, api, sdk, android-api-levels

I'm very new to Android development and this is one of my first projects. I realized that my API Level is set to 20 when datepicker gave an "exception rasied during rendering" error.

I wanted to change the API level to 19 as the API 20 is set to wearable devices. I have installed the API 19 SDK but it doesnt appear for selection during development.

I have also tried to set -

minSdkVersion 10

targetSdkVersion 20

on build gradle but it doesn't work.

I cannot run the emulator as the API is set to 20 and it will display error on a watch :(

How do I set make the API 19 as one of the options during development as I already installed the SDK?

Comment: Have you changed the value in both AndroidManifest and build.gradle ?

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
compileSdkVersion 19
```

in your build.gradle.

`minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` control app installation and runtime backwards compatibility modes, not the SDK you build with.